# How do programs like Apache Airflow/ Luigi determine shortest path?

Tags: etl, airflow, graph-theory, shortest-path, luigi

I am looking for a simple layman's term explanation or a reference to read on how do programs like Apache Airflow or Luigi determine the shortest path to complete a certain task and make it possible to parallelize it? And how does that, if any, relate to graph theory?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com) or [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange forum as it is question about algorithm and not about a particular programming issue.

Comment: The question concerns a specific software algorithm, so I think it is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.